# changing a nested child fields from its parent in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a widget A that has a nested widget B. I need to update a field on B (maybe by calling a function of B) when user click on a button in A.  How can I do it?

EDIT: more details

Widget B is a widget that I use across my app so I want to leave him as a separate widget. Widget A is composed of widget B plus another button and I want that click on the button will change the the text that inside Widget B

EDIT2 - what I want to achieve:
Widget B is actually a Container that contains TextFormField with some other widgets. I use it for 5 form fields. now I want to add a field for location. the field for location consists of B plus a list that open when user type and there are results from google geocode. When the user clicks on one of the results, I want to set the TextFormField controller text to the value the user type.
So, I don't want to copy all logic and widgets for the text field from B to A.

In my code widget B is FormTextField and A is LocationField

```
class LocationField extends StatefulWidget {
  Location meetingPointData;

    LocationField(this.meetingPointData):  super();

      @override
    _LocationFieldFieldState createState() => new _LocationFieldFieldState();
}



class _LocationFieldFieldState extends State<LocationField>  {

OverlayEntry _overlayEntry;
var addresses;
final LayerLink _layerLink = LayerLink();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

  }

  onLocationInputChanged(text) {
    this.findLocations(text);
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return CompositedTransformTarget(
      link: this._layerLink,
      child: FormTextField('meetingPoint', 'Meeting Point', "", "enter the name of a place or an address", TextInputType.text, onLocationInputChanged, true ,  {"empty":  "Please enter the meeting point"})
    );
  }

  OverlayEntry _createOverlayEntry() {

    RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject();
    var size = renderBox.size;

    var addressesWidget =  <Widget>[];
    for(var i=0; i< addresses.length; i++) {
      addressesWidget.add( ListTile(
                    title: Text(addresses[i].addressLine),
                     onTap: () {
                       widget.meetingPointData = Location(addresses[i].addressLine);

                       setState(() {});

                        this._overlayEntry.remove();
                       this._overlayEntry = null;
                    },
                  ),);
    }

   return OverlayEntry(
      builder: (context) => Positioned(
        width: size.width,
        child: CompositedTransformFollower(
          link: this._layerLink,
          showWhenUnlinked: false,
          offset: Offset(10.0, size.height - 45.0),
          child: Material(
            elevation: 4.0,
            child: ListView(
              padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: addressesWidget
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  Future findLocations(text) async {
    if(text == "") {
      addresses = [];
      return;
    }
    // From a query
    final query = text;
    try {
          addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
          var first = addresses.first;
          print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
    } catch (err) {

    }

    if(addresses.length > 0) {
      if(this._overlayEntry != null) {
        this._overlayEntry.remove();
        this._overlayEntry = null;
      }
        this._overlayEntry = this._createOverlayEntry();
        Overlay.of(context).insert(this._overlayEntry);

    } else {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is widget B `StatefulWidget`? Can you please share the code?

Comment: Why isn't the text inside B a parameter?

Comment: the text is inside B, but it is part of complex container widget in B. i need it to stay in B but I want that when user click on a button in A, it will update the text in B

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the widget tree you're thinking of is:

```dart
A(
  child: B(),
);
```

Then `A` should **not** be able to modify the state of `B`. Even if it is technically possible through global variables/GlobalKey, it is anti-pattern to do so.

Instead, you should move the state up in the tree and store your field inside A instead of B.